# Parse device user agent in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple user agent parser. However, when I use user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

or

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

the browser keeps showing value of `$OS` and `$osArr[1]` instead of echoing "Device unknown".

```
<?php
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ; SM-577) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";


$osStart = strpos($user_agent, "(") + 1;
$osEnd = strpos($user_agent, ";", $osStart); 
$osInfo = substr($user_agent, $osStart, $osEnd - $osStart); 
$osArr = explode("; ", $osInfo); 
$os = $osArr[0]; 

// Ekstrak  device information
$deviceStart = strpos($user_agent, ";", $osEnd) + 2; 
$deviceEnd = strpos($user_agent, ")", $deviceStart); 
$device = substr($user_agent, $deviceStart, $deviceEnd - $deviceStart); 

// show information on browser
if (empty(trim($device))) {
    echo "DEVICE UNKNOWN.";
} else {
    echo $os . "<br>";
    echo $osArr[1] . "<br>";
    echo $device;
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

For the first user agent you mentioned:

```php
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36';

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `(` character encountered:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (
 *             ↑
 *            12
 */
$osStart = strpos($user_agent, "(") + 1; // $osStart = 12 + 1 = 13

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `;` character encountered on or after 
 * the index 13 character:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;
 *              ↑    ↑
 *             13   18
 */
$osEnd = strpos($user_agent, ";", $osStart);  // $osEnd = 18

/**
 * Extract a string from `$user_agent`, starting from index `$osStart` (13)
 * and that is `$osEnd - $osStart` (18 - 13 = 5) in length:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (|Linux|
 *              |     |
 *             13←-5→18
 */
$osInfo = substr($user_agent, $osStart, $osEnd - $osStart); // $osInfo = 'Linux'

/**
 * Make an array, where each entry is a substring of `$osInfo`, where each 
 * entry is a substring of `$osInfo`, delimited by the character sequence `; `.
 * 
 * However, since `$osInfo` (`'Linux'`) does not contain the character sequence
 * `; `, we get a 1-member array of the full string.
 */
$osArr = explode("; ", $osInfo); // $osArr = ['Linux']

/**
 * Get the value of the member with the index `0`. In numerically-indexed 
 * arrays like the one generated by `explode()` previously, this will be
 * the first element.
 */
$os = $osArr[0]; // $os = 'Linux';

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `;` character encountered on or after 
 * the index 18 character:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;
 *                   ↑
 *                  18
 */
// Ekstrak  device information
$deviceStart = strpos($user_agent, ";", $osEnd) + 2; // $deviceStart = 18 + 2 = 20

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `)` character encountered on or after 
 * the index 20 character:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ; )
 *                     ↑           ↑
 *                    20          32
 */
$deviceEnd = strpos($user_agent, ")", $deviceStart);  // $deviceEnd = 32

/**
 * Extract a string from `$user_agent`, starting from index `$deviceStart` (20)
 * and that is `$deviceEnd - $deviceStart` (32 - 20 = 12) in length:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; |Android 9 ; |)
 *                     |            |
 *                    20 ←-- 12 -→ 32
 */
$device = substr($user_agent, $deviceStart, $deviceEnd - $deviceStart); // $device = 'Android 9 ; '

/**
 * Trim any leading or ending whitespace from `$device`:
 *
 * trim($device) = trim('Android 9 ; ') = 'Android 9 ;'
 *
 * Test if the result of the `trim()` is a falsey string, i.e. if it is an
 * empty string (`''`) or string zero (`'0'`). The result of the `trim()` is
 * 'Android 9 ;' so it does not pass this if check. We move to the `else` 
 * branch.
 */
// show information on browser
if (  empty(trim($device)) ) {
    echo "DEVICE UNKNOWN.";
} else {
    echo $os . "<br>"; // Linux<br/>
   
    /**
     * $osArr has only one member of key `0`, so this statement will emit
     * a warning, `Undefined array key 1`, meaning that a member of a non-
     * existent key was attempted to be accessed.
     */
    echo $osArr[1] . "<br>";

    echo $device; // Android 9 ;
}
```

For the second user agent string:

```php
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36';

// Code between is the same as above, skipped for brevity.

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `)` character encountered on or after 
 * the index 20 character:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 )
 *                     ↑         ↑
 *                    20        30
 */
$deviceEnd = strpos($user_agent, ")", $deviceStart);  // $deviceEnd = 30

/**
 * Extract a string from `$user_agent`, starting from index `$deviceStart` (20)
 * and that is `$deviceEnd - $deviceStart` (30 - 20 = 10) in length:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; |Android 9 |)
 *                     |          |
 *                    20 ←- 10 → 30
 */
$device = substr($user_agent, $deviceStart, $deviceEnd - $deviceStart); // $device = 'Android 9 '

/**
 * Trim any leading or ending whitespace from `$device`:
 *
 * trim($device) = trim('Android 9 ') = 'Android 9'
 *
 * Test if the result of the `trim()` is a falsey string, i.e. if it is an
 * empty string (`''`) or string zero (`'0'`). The result of the `trim()` is
 * 'Android 9' so it does not pass this if check. We move to the `else` 
 * branch.
 */
// show information on browser
if (  empty(trim($device)) ) {
    echo "DEVICE UNKNOWN.";
} else {
    echo $os . "<br>"; // Linux<br/>
   
    /**
     * $osArr has only one member of key `0`, so this statement will emit
     * a warning, `Undefined array key 1`, meaning that a member of a non-
     * existent key was attempted to be accessed.
     */
    echo $osArr[1] . "<br>";

    echo $device; // Android 9
}
```

## Fix

It seems like you are after parsing the information in the first set of parentheses, where you expect the data to be delimited by semi-colons `;` and where the first two items are for OS information, and the third (if any) is for the device. Here is an alternative approach which will work for both user agent string examples provided:

```php
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36';

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `(` character encountered:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (
 *             ↑
 *            12
 */
$infoStart = strpos($user_agent, "(") + 1; // $infoStart = 12 + 1 = 13

/**
 * Get the 0-index position of the first `)` character encountered:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9 ; )
 *                                 ↑
 *                                32
 */
$infoEnd = strpos($user_agent, ")"); // $infoStart = 32

/**
 * Extract a string from `$user_agent`, starting from index `$infoStart` (13) 
 * and that is `$infoEnd - $infoStart` (32 - 13 = 19) in length:
 *
 * Mozilla/5.0 (|Linux; Android 9 ; |)
 *              |                   |
 *             13 ←----- 19 -----→ 32
 */
$info = substr($user_agent, $infoStart, $infoEnd - $infoStart); // $osInfo = 'Linux; Android 9 ; '


/**
 * Make an array, where each entry is a substring of `$info`, where each entry 
 * is a substring of `$info`, delimited by the character sequence `;`.
 */
$infoParts = explode(";", $info); // $infoParts = ['Linux', ' Android 9 ', ' ']

/**
 * Get the element with key `2`, or if it does not exist, use `''`:
 * 
 * $infoParts[2] ?? '' = ' '
 * 
 * Trim any leading or ending whitespace:
 *
 * trim($infoParts[2] ?? '') = trim(' ') = ''
 *
 * Test if it is an empty string (`''`) or whether it is string zero (`'0'`).
 * It is an empty string, so passes the `if` check:
 */
if (empty(trim($infoParts[2] ?? ''))) {
  echo "DEVICE UNKNOWN.";
} else {
  echo implode($infoParts, "<br/>");
}
```